# Redirect if PHP code does not find video

Tags: php, html

I have a video folder that contains MP4 videos. My PHP code looks into that folder and gets the name of one video and populates an HTML5 `video` element with the name.

```
$fname = $files[0];
```

[0] In the php represents the first MP4 video. If i change this to [1] it will populate the video tag with the second mp4 video, and if I change it to [2] it will get the next MP4 video name.

This all works as I only have 3 MP4 videos in the folder. But what I need is a redirect if it can't find a video in the folder.

At the moment, if I take out one of the videos from the folder, I get a php error:

> NOTICE: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\video1.php on line 18.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Tv Web Video1</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.cycle.all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#A9A9A9">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content">
       <div>
<?php 
 $files = glob('videos/*.mp4'); // get all .mp4 files from folder
$fname = $files[0]; // get 1st filename 
$ftext = ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', basename($fname, '.mp4'))); // format text for display
?>
<video id="video" class="box" poster="poster.jpg" preload="metadata" controls muted width="100%" 
max-width:500px;  height="50%" max-height:500px; autoplay onended="window.location = '/video2.php';">
     <source src="<?php echo $fname; ?>"/>
</video> 

<div id="infobox" class="box">Video: '<b><?php echo $ftext; ?></b>'</div>
<ul id="playlist" class="box">
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `At them moment if i take out one of the videos for the folder i get a php error NOTICE: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\video1.php on line 18.` Seems like you're not running it on `localhost`?

Comment: Hi HawasKaPujaari no it is on a local host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `empty()`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tv Web Video1</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.cycle.all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#A9A9A9">
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        <div>
            <?php
                $files = glob('videos/*.mp4');
                $fname = $files[0];
                $ftext = ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', basename($fname, '.mp4')));

                if(!empty($files))
                {
                    ?>
                    <video id="video" class="box" poster="poster.jpg" preload="metadata" controls muted width="100%" autoplay onended="window.location = '/video2.php'">
                        <source src="<?php echo $fname; ?>"/>
                    </video>

                    <div id="infobox" class="box">Video: '<b><?php echo $ftext; ?></b>'</div>
                    <ul id="playlist" class="box">
                    </ul>
                    <?
                }
                else
                {

                    header("Location: http://example.com/myOtherPage.php");

                }
            ?>

        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i use header to redirect page

Comment: @ACD check now. Updated

Comment: Can you really use header() in PHP when there's already been output sent?

Comment: on where ?? line number??

Comment: Got it working i moved else and header into the php tag that contains if empty

Comment: Thanks for all your Help Abdulla